# Pyqgis script to join delimited text layer on KML and create graduated symbols

Tags: pyqgis, kml, geohash

I need to create multiple maps from QGIS which have the same procedure and so wanted to write a script. I found little help in terms of how to join delimited text layer to a KML vector layer(of geohashes) and create a graduated style based on counts for each geohash.

I need help on writing pyqgis commands and create a script for the following actions done in QGIS.

Steps in qgis:

1) Load KML file
python:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\Test.kml", "Test", "ogr")
```

2) Add delimited text layer on KML vector layer

3) Create graduated symbols based on counts at geohash

What would be the commands to achieve steps 2 and 3 in python?